# CKEditor5: prevent nested same-type elements from automatically inheriting parent's attributes

Tags: ckeditor5

Is there a way to prevent nested same-type elements from automatically inheriting parent's attributes?

Eg:

```
<div class='border'>
  <div class='shade'></div>
  <div class='shade'></div>
</div>
```

is automatically translated to:

```
<div class='border'>
  <div class='border shade'></div>
  <div class='border shade'></div>
</div>
```

Excerpt from plugin:

```
editor.model.schema.register ('div', {
  inheritAllFrom: '$root',
  allowWhere: '$block',
  isLimit: true,
  allowAttributes: ['border', 'shade'],
} );

editor.conversion.elementToElement (
  { model: 'div', view: 'div', }
);

editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute ( { model: 'border', view: { key: 'class', value: 'border' } } );
editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute ( { model: 'shade', view: { key: 'class', value: 'shade' } } );
```

Comment: I think this may be a bug. I'll pass this to my colleague to check.

Comment: This is a bug, I reported an issue: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/issues/1443

Comment: We merged a fix already. But we'll publish it in ~3 weeks because we've just had a release.